# Normal map doesn`t work on Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine, normals, normal-map

Painted model in SP. Created Normal map.
But in Blender there are artifacts, it doesn`t show any normal map effect. But mesh gets Sharper...
+Normal map applies with wrong UV (Applied Texture Coordinate - didnt work...)
Here some images from Blender and SP.
[image: First image]

[image: Second imgae]

[image: SP]

Comment: if Jo xXx's answer is not good, please pack the images and share the boot object: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Didn`t work. Uploaded Blender file (with Packed images) : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=kQ4w1wAv" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kQ4w1wAv/)

Comment: thanks but I can't see any image, you need to go into File > External Data > Pack Resources, then save

Comment: Sorry,my bad: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gnQ0SGg4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gnQ0SGg4/)    uploaded )

Comment: Switch the Normal Map from Object Space to Tangent Space?

Comment: moonboots is right, change to tangent space. Also make sure your normal map texture is set to non-color.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the *Normal Map* from *Object Space* to *Tangent Space*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Everyone!! Will keep it in mind  :D

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the photo color space to non color.

A good idea is to add an input vector from its source object. You can set this up like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maps made in Substance Painter (and designer) are by default optimised for DirectX, whereas blender uses OpenGL for its shading calculations. Often, to look correct, you need to give the normal map a *DirectX to OpenGL Conversion* (Highlighted Below):

[image: Conversion]